# Binding problems using MVVM with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, binding

I'm new to the C#. 
I'm having troubles in binding. I will leave here the code example and hope that you can help me find the troubles.

**FriendsView**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfWHERE.View.FriendsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfWHERE.View"
         xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfWHERE.ViewModel"
         xmlns:data = "clr-namespace:WpfWHERE.Model"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:FriendsViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<UserControl.Resources><DataGrid x:Key="friendsList" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource = "{Binding Student}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="150">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cbName" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FullName, Mode=OneWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**FriendsViewModel**

```
public class FriendsViewModel:AViewModel
{
    #region fields
    public DelegateCommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }
    #endregion fields

    #region constructors
    public FriendsViewModel()
    {
        LoadStudents();
        DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnDelete, CanDelete);
    }
    #endregion constructors
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void LoadStudents()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Student> students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

        students.Add(new Student { FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "Allain" ,Place = "Home"});
        students.Add(new Student { FirstName = "Allen", LastName = "Brown", Place = "China" });
        students.Add(new Student { FirstName = "Linda", LastName = "Hamerski", Place = "Je" });

        Students = students;
    }

    private Student _selectedStudent;

    public Student SelectedStudent
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedStudent;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedStudent = value;
            DeleteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnDelete()
    {
        Students.Remove(SelectedStudent);
    }

    private bool CanDelete()
    {
        return SelectedStudent != null;
    }
}
```

**Student**

```
public class StudentModel { }

public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string place;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }

        set
        {
            if (firstName != value)
            {
                firstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
                RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }

        set
        {
            if (lastName != value)
            {
                lastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
                RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }
    public string Place
    {
        get { return place; }

        set
        {
            if (place != value)
            {
                place = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Place");
            }
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName + " " + lastName;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, I google and stacked a bit but can't make it work. I hope you can share the knowledge and help me.

Best regards,

Comment: Skipping the fact that you're not even telling what the problem is, you're binding `friendList` to a property named `Student`, which... doesn't exist.

Comment: Student is my model. I'm trying to bind this. Still learning this MVVM architecture...

Comment: ItemsSource should be set to your collection. Change it to `ItemsSource = "{Binding Students}"` (i.e. the property name of your collection)

Comment: @Tone still don't work http://i.imgur.com/iNiNiQl.png

Comment: That's the name of your student class, which means it's correctly binding the items to your DataGrid but it doesn't know how to display them. I don't really understand what you're trying to show in your DataGrid, it looks like you're creating a grid of students (1 row for each), but also each row will have a ComboBox containing the full list of student. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Tone In this first approach I'm trying to create a DataGrid with one column with each row being one student (just showing the name). In the next iteration I want to put more columns but the approach should be the same. I replace the combobox with <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path = FullName, Mode = OneWay}" ></TextBlock> but still didn't work

Comment: Do you have a public FullName property on your Student class? The TextBlock version should work if you do.

Comment: @Tone I updated my question with my modal. But yes I have FullName property in the model. Didn't work :(

Comment: Your question should include a _precisely stated problem statement_. It should also include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Please improve your question so that it is more clear, so that it does not require anyone to infer code that you haven't included, and so that it doesn't include any code that is not _strictly_ required in order to reproduce your problem. Be sure to explain precisely what the code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I only forgot to put the model. My question is clear, I don't understand what is wrong. But thanks for the link and the help.

Comment: I've posted an answer with some sample code that works for me. Could you try pasting that code in please or update your question with the actual code you're using now that still isn't working.

Comment: It worked. I already thumbed up your answer. Thanks man. Stay strong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking note of the 2 changes in the comments

a) Using `ItemsSource = "{Binding Students}` instead of `ItemsSource = "{Binding Student}`

b) Using a TextBlock with syntax `<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path = FullName, Mode = OneWay}" ></TextBlock>`

The following amended code for your `FriendsView` should give the desired `DataGrid` result. Tested and working on my end to show a DataGrid with a single column showing the `FullName`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfWHERE.View.FriendsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfWHERE.View"
         xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfWHERE.ViewModel"
         xmlns:data = "clr-namespace:WpfWHERE.Model"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:FriendsViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataGrid x:Key="friendsList" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource = "{Binding Students}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path = FullName, Mode = OneWay}" ></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource friendsList}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Just to note:

1) I've displayed the `DataGrid` in a `ContentControl` as I'm not sure how you're displaying it.

2) I'm not sure what you have in your `AViewModel` but it shouldn't affect the result

Comment: Perfect, it works. AViewModel is the common ViewModelBase. What is the difference between using a Content control or putting the DataGrid directly outside the UserControl.Resources?

Comment: You typically define things with a `x:Key` in `UserControl.Resources` if you want to reuse it in multiple places. Then you use the `x:Key` to refer to it as a `StaticResource`. If you're only using it once you can just put the `DataGrid` outside of UserControl.Resources and omit the `x:Key` (`x:Key` not valid outside of the Resources section). I just put it in a `ContentControl` so I could reference the `x:key` to match your code.

Comment: awesome explanation. Just one more thing, the thing can be reused in other views like a Style template in App.xml or just in that one?

Comment: If you want to use it in multiple views, define it in `Application.Resources` in `App.xaml`. Other resource blocks are local only to the control (e.g. `UserControl.Resources` is resources for that `UserControl`, `StackPanel.Resources` is resources for that `StackPanel`, etc.)

Comment: You mentioned in the comments above that you thumbed up my answer. I'm not sure what you meant but it hasn't accepted or voted. If you had intended to accept my answer (your choice) you might want to check out [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: I clicked in the arrow but you are right and I didn't have accepted your answer. It's done now :)